# Increase disk size from terminal after increasing size from azure

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu-18.04

I have 30 GB base memory disk on azure and another 64 GB that I increased from 32 GB but I am having issues with allocating the newly added memory.

here is my output of `df-h`  [terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqSBI.png)

any idea how to allocate the memory? Thanks

output of `fdisk -l` as root is-

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 44.6 MiB, 46710784 bytes, 91232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 116.7 MiB, 122359808 bytes, 238984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 63.3 MiB, 66347008 bytes, 129584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 44.7 MiB, 46886912 bytes, 91576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 63.2 MiB, 66301952 bytes, 129496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32213303296 bytes, 62916608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 342F2050-6D7E-4556-921C-FEB527AA3DFB

Device      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1  227328 62916574 62689247 29.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda14   2048    10239     8192    4M BIOS boot
/dev/sda15  10240   227327   217088  106M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa175f7ec

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 67106815 67104768  32G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdc: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: what is the result of `fdisk -l` (as root)?

Comment: Hey @RomeoNinov I have updated it on question

Comment: I see one disk `dev/sdc` 64GB, which is unallocated. Do you search for this?

Comment: Hey yes but how to allocate this? I tried resize2fs dev/sdc which returned open: No such file or directory while opening dev/sdc

Comment: You need to create partition there. But in your case you can't add space from this disk to other disks (if this is your intention).

Comment: oh because of different disk types ? @RomeoNinov

Comment: No, because to use diskspace as one big bucket you need to use LVM for example. And from what I see you don't. If you want to extend existing partition you should extend existing disks (`sda`, `sdb`)

Comment: Hello @RomeoNinov I have fixed the issue I was getting by increasing the size of base disc instead of adding additional disc. So when I increased the size of base/primary disc it automatically increased the size. I will look into how to allocate using LVM and thank you very for the insights :)

Comment: Right now you do not want to play with LVM because there is no sample way to migrate existing data to LVM :)